# Telerik ASP.Net MVC Grid: How filterable option to use both "menu" and "row" modes simultaneously?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, grid

This Example, writing Kendo UI Grid

```
  <div id="grid"></div>
    <script>
        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            columns: [
                { field: "name" },
                { field: "age" }
            ],
            filterable: {
                mode: "menu, row"
            },
            dataSource: [
                { name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
                { name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
            ]
      });
    </script>
```

this , `mode: "menu, row"` but option missing MVC Grid.
Because, MVC in

```
namespace Kendo.Mvc.UI
{
    public enum GridFilterMode
    {
        Row = 1,
        Menu = 2
    }
}
```

Missing just like `RowMenu=3` option.

How convert to ASP.Net MVC Grid ? please help Telerik Team or Masters.

Answer (score 1):

was very simple,

```
.Filterable(filterable => filterable.Mode(GridFilterMode.Menu | GridFilterMode.Row))
```

thanks for JustDecompile